# Trouble reading input from console using Scanner in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read a bunch of inputs from console using the `Scanner` class in Java. 
Following is my code:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the number of vertices");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int numOfVertices = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please name the vertices");
HashMap<String, Integer> nameNumMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < numOfVertices; i++) {
  nameNumMap.put(scanner.next(), i);
}

Set<String> keySet = nameNumMap.keySet();
String[] response = new String[numOfVertices];
int i = 0;
for (String key : keySet) {
  System.out.println("Please enter the vertices connected to " + key + " separated by ','");
 String response[i] = scanner.nextLine();
 if (i<numOfVertices)
    i++;
}

System.out.println("Responses are:");
for (String res : response) {
  System.out.println(res);
}
```

**Output at console**

```
Please enter the number of vertices
3
Please name the vertices
A B C D E F 
Please enter the vertices connected to A separated by ','
Please enter the vertices connected to B separated by ','
A
Please enter the vertices connected to C separated by ','
D
null
null
null
```

If `numOfVertices` is 3, shouldn't the scanner class ideally stop taking input after the 3rd element? Shouldn't it stop allowing the user to give any more input after the space-bar on the keyboard is pressed after entering C?

Besides, why am I getting two lines printed next instead of one and why are the values taken from the console coming as null?

Comment: I would suggest that you add a `System.out.println` immediately after every input as verification of what the program has received as input. That should help you debug your code.

Comment: @Bohemian this is not a duplicate. This problem is related to the user believing that the space bar is a default tokenizer for `Scanner.next()`


@auro You need to pass a pattern into next() if you want to only take the numbers that separated by spaces. You'll also need to change how your reading in your input because scanner.nextInt() does not increment the line that scanner.next() and scanner.nextLine() read

Comment: @Thatalent OK, post your answer

Answer (score 0):

Scanner.next() will not read the input unless you press enter or pass in a pattern when calling the method. You can also pass in a delimiter for the scanner so that you only read the strings within a the delimiters, but for what you have I believe pattern matching would be simpler.

Below is your code modified so that it takes in text values and reads them within one line separated by space.

If you apply pattern matching to `next()` it will be easy to change the portion that reads the vertices to read string between commas.

```
static void main(String[]args){

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of vertices");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numOfVertices = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Please name the vertices");
    HashMap<String, Integer> nameNumMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfVertices; i++) {
     nameNumMap.put(scanner.next("\\w"), i);
    }
    scanner.skip("\\s*\\w*");
    Set<String> keySet = nameNumMap.keySet();
    String[] response = new String[numOfVertices];
    int i = 0;
    for (String key : keySet) {
      System.out.println("Please enter the vertices connected to " + key + " and press enter");
    response[i] = scanner.next();
    if (i<numOfVertices)
       i++;
    }

    System.out.println("Responses are:");
    for (String res : response) {
      System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```